# Script to execute blender on cluster calculator

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, animation, scripting

I am doing a large project. I have had  100 animation scenarios (on cycles render) and each one will be applied on 100 different persons using MakeHuman. Each scenario among the 100 is constructed and finally imported as .bvh file. After that, I need to apply each scenario on all persons to get finally 10000 scenario. I need to do automatically this work because rendering need time. So I am wondering if it is possible to write a script that import each .bvh and apply it on each person and render the result? And I need to run this script on a cluster calculator. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: While it's certainly possible to automate this, can you narrow down your question?

Comment: @MikePan, I did not understand you? did you mean that my question is too wide?

Comment: Yes it is too vague(wide). If you are simply wondering if it is possible to create such a script, then yes, it is possible. But StackExchange works best as a focused Q&A place. It would be impossible to help you write the script since we don't know your exact specification.

Comment: @MikePan, It is right. I did not ask for solution but I ask if it is possible or no because I have never write any script.